# Database news with gallery, categories as year and subcategory

Tags: sql, database-design

at the moment I'm working on database project news with gallery. I would like to know, if I thinking in a good way, or not.

```
news
------
idNews (P)
title
content
CategoryId (FK)
PublishedDate


gallery
--------
idGallery (P)
idNews (FK)
Image


category
---------
idCategory (P)
categoryName
```

P - Primary Key,
FK - Foreign Key

For Example:
After adding some rows into a news, in the same time a part of the information about news must have to be add into the other tables like gallery (image),subcategory( as 'test'), and category( '2018' ). This is a good idea of my database project, or not? What If in 2019, someone wants to add some images into the same subcategoryName as 'test'? If this is not enough information, please ask me anything you want.

Comment: You cann add column year in category table and  to be part ok pk, also sub category should be info about the category not the news you can create a table news_info or news_desc for that.. by the way it depends on ur model if you want image name to be unique then (same image doesnt have the same name) then name should be in pk and add year column.

Comment: In category table, I would like to contains information like: '2016/2017', '2017/2018', and then I will want to receive images which have that category. Is it clear?

Comment: For good data modeling and later performance its better you put column start year 2016 and other column end year 2017 and the you can get that category.. is that what you want? For ex select * from category where start_date ='2016' and end_date ='2018'

Comment: This database will be for my school, and this table probably contains string '2016/2017', I didn't see their database yet so I really don't know, how to do that. That's only my idea. @edit: I think, that u have a really nice concept. I have never working on a large database ( I'm a student ), so my brain is tight :|

Comment: Ok so whats your question? I adviced you in my previous comments if not that what you want then please explain more

Comment: I changed contents in this topic. Could you check this current database project?@edit: and now I think, I can get year by PublishedDate, and then selecting all rows which have in that column year between 2016 and 2017, as u wished :)

Comment: I add my comments as answer if you need athor help tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add column year in category table and to be part ok pk, also sub category should be info about the category not the news you can create a table news_info or news_desc for that.. by the way it depends on ur model if you want image name to be unique then (same image doesnt have the same name) then name should be in pk and add year column.

For good data modeling and later performance its better you put column start year 2016 and other column end year 2017 and the you can get that category.. is that what you want? For ex select * from category where start_date ='2016' and end_date ='2018'.

For example  if you want the data between 2015 and 2020 its better to day where start date ='2015' and end date ='2020' then to sort th3n while they are 2015/2016 or 2016/2017